# Mongodb Transactions Unhandled Promise Rejection Error - MongoError: Retryable write with is prohibited on session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, nestjs

Using Mongodb transactions with withTransaction Helper in nodejs (nestjs framework), These errors are popping up

```
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Retryable write with txnNumber 3552 is prohibited on session 8a19417e-8bbd-46c5-9aab-04a2cb60f406 - /C5A+ZfCloKsJhH+D
    aIABeIyRV1uALaRfamlKu9yI5I= because a newer retryable write with txnNumber 3553 has already started on this session.

at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:263:20) 
at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at processIncomingData (/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
at MessageStream._write(/home/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
```

Can anyone help me with what it means, or point me to any resources explaining this, there is very limited documentation for this particular error.

Comment: You are not using the driver and/or sessions properly and are trying to issue overlapping operations. Common mistake in node environment.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, Overlapping operations meaning overlapping transactions? , is there any documentation or resources you can point me to explaining this error in detail.

Comment: No, any operations would do that. Common example is if a process is forked and child uses the same client object and subobjects as parent and ends up using the same transaction numbers for different operations in the same session. If you misuse callbacks or promises I imagine you could end up with this error also. I don't know specifically why you are getting it, you need to look through your code and compare against official documentation to verify proper usage.